# Unique extendable functions... Is there a theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I also made this post in MSE, but I think it may fit here as well.

*Motivation*: Take a continuous function $f$ from a topological space $X$ to a hausdorff space $Y$. If $g$ is a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ that coincides with $f$ in a dense set, then $g=f$.

Take an analytic function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. If $g$ is an analytic function that coincides with $f$ in a set with limit point, then $g=f$.

Okay, now given the motivation, my question is the following:

**Is there a theory which has the objective of characterizing functions that satisfy a certain "unique extension" property, in a general context?**

For example, we could define:

> Definition: Given a family $\mathcal{F} $ of maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ , $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is said to satisfy *$P$-unique-extendability on $(X,Y)$* if for every subset $A \subset X$ which satisfies the property $P$, we have that every function $g \in \mathcal{F}$ which coincides with $f$ in $A$ is such that $f=g$.

Therefore, for example, every continuous function is *dense-unique-extendable on $(\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R})$*

Maybe there is a categorical POV of this?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the categorical notion of [epimorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism).  It is unclear to me what you expect a general theory to do; in such generality, it seems very unlikely to me that you can actually say anything interesting.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I agree with you, but what I mean is: maybe searching for those things in spaces we already know, in order to characterize objects which satisfy it, could be something fruitful.